# MATLAB submatrix

Tags: matlab, projection, submatrix

MATLAB question:

I have an array A(2,2,2) that is three-dimensional. I would like to define a 2x2 array as a subarray of A, as follows:

B = A(1,:,:).

That is, we are simply projecting on the first component. But matlab will now treat this 2x2 matrix as a 1x2x2 array instead, so that I can't do certain things (like multiply by another 2x2 matrix).

How do I get B as a 2x2 subarray of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about a skyscraper, your `A(1,:,:)` is taking the first floor out and this operation inevitably happens across the 3rd dimension.

You can use [`reshape()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), [`squeeze()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) or [`permute()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to get rid of the singleton dimension:

```
reshape(A(1,:,:),2,2)
squeeze(A(1,:,:))
permute(A(1,:,:),[2,3,1])
```

`squeeze()` pretty much does all the job by itself, however it is not an inbuilt function and in fact uses `reshape()`. The other two alternatives are expected to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use the function [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) which removes the singleton dimensions:

```
B = squeeze(A(1,:,:))
```